# Use Dagger to inject different Retrofit and OkHttp object before and after login

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I have my `Retrofit` and `OkHttp` instances injected. I am changing the headers of my OkHttp object using an `Interceptor`. In this Interceptor, I set information such as app name, version etc.

I am now adding a login and want to set an `authToken` to the headers. However, this only exists AFTER login, obviously. So what I want to do is be able to add a new header after login for authToken. However, I can't get access to my OkHttp object as its buried in my module, and I just get my RestClient object injected in my class, with everything else built.

I was thinking of copying all my `provides...` code and making duplicates for before an after Login. For example, wrap my RestClient in a class called "PreLoginApi" that doesn't have authToken, and then creating another wrapper class called "PostLoginApi" which has the authToken, but this won't work if Dagger creates the objects on app launch.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("HeaderInterceptor")
fun provideHeaderInterceptor(context: Context): Interceptor {
    val headerMap = context.getHeaderMap()
    return Interceptor { chain ->
        val original = chain.request()
        val builder = original.newBuilder()
        headerMap.keys.forEach {
            builder.addHeader(it, headerMap[it] ?: "")
        }
        val request = builder.build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }
}

@Provides
fun providesOkHttpClient(
    @Named("HeaderInterceptor") headerInterceptor: Interceptor,
): OkHttpClient {
    val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
    return builder.build()
}
```

You can see here where I call my extension function `Context.getHeaderMap()`. Inside this function, I'm retrieving the authToken from `EncryptedSharedPreferences`.

So ideally, I'd like to be able to tell Dagger to redo this initialisation once I login, because at this stage the authToken will be set. Is it possible to just re-initialise this one module or will I have to wrap my RestClient in another class, and maybe use Lazy loading to initialise the "PostLoginApi"?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I do similar for Firebase FCM token, where I pass in the headerMap during initialisation, like this:

```
private fun updateFirebaseToken(headerMap: HashMap<String, String>) {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            return@OnCompleteListener
        }

        // Get new FCM registration token
        task.result?.let { token ->
            headerMap["FirebaseId"] = token
        }
    })
}
```

But I don't think I can do something like this for a SharedPrefs value.

Comment: Can you set things up so that the Authentication header is added to your interceptor for every request but only actually sent if not null? That's what I'd look to do

Comment: Either go with IvanWooll suggestion, or provide 2 different OkHttpClient  with @Named annotation to separate the authenticated from the non-authenticated. Then inject the correct client to the relevant API layer. If this isn't clear enough let me know and I'll post a more complete answer.

Comment: @IvanWooll The Interceptor is built once at app launch. I don't think it will read from SharedPrefs each time an API request is made, as the RetroFit instance is created and locked in. I solved this for FCM token (see my EDIT) but not sure if this can be done for a SharedPref value.

Comment: @gioravered I had already started writing the code for the @Named variations but thought it was so much duplicate code so wanted to find a better way, as I'll also have to create a parent wrapper class and then add that to the `LoginModule` (will it override whats in my `NetworkModule`?), but if you have a nice clean sample you'd like to share, then please do! Thanks

Comment: It's not a lot of code duplication in my opinion.. For me it's just a duplication of the OkHttpClient provide methods. One of them accepts an Authentication Interceptor and the other is not. Also, In order to address the issue about the SharedPreferences, you can wrap it with a class that exposes an accessToken variable and using a get() loads from SharedPreferences only if the variable is null.

Comment: Well, not a lot, but 3 functions that are basically identical, in order to get it to rebuild the headerMap after login when the token is set. Then I'll have to write the code to make it lazy, which is something I'm less experienced with in Dagger.

Comment: It's your call.. But again, I have a dedicated Interceptor for Access Token and another for the rest. Then I only have 2 provide methods for OkHttpClient. One that includes the access token interceptor and one that doesn't.